# GPG keys for mailinglists

Tags: email, encryption, gnupg, mailing-lists

There are two mailing-lists (e.g. *list1@foo.bar* and *list2@foo.bar*) for which I'd like to generate GPG keys and send the respective private keys to the members of the lists, so mails to the lists can be sent encrypted without having to know the pubkeys of the members of those lists. - So far.

Further there is an alias address, of which mails are forwarded to both mailing-lists (e.g. mails to *both@foo.bar* are forwarded to *list1@foo.bar* and *list2@foo.bar*).

```
                       | 
                       V
Alias:             both@foo.bar
                       /\
                      /  \
                     /    \
                    /      \
                   /        \
                  /          \
                 /            \
                V              V
Lists:    list1@foo.bar    list2@foo.bar
```

How can I include this second address/identity so that both lists can decrypt mails that are sent to *both@foo.bar*, without having to generate a 3rd keypair for *both@foo.bar*?

The problem is that when I add *both@foo.bar* as second identity to *list1@foo.bar* and *list2@foo.bar*, the senders mail-client will encrypt it to one key only (*list1@foo.bar* or *list2@foo.bar* and not both).

I also tried to generate a second subkey in *list1@foo.bar* which I exported and tried to import to *list2@foo.bar*, which failed.

Is this doable at all or does this have to be solved via an mta/mda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution 1: shared secret

I fear there is no easy, clean solution. If you don't want the others to have to encrypt to multiple keys, you'll need a shared secret key between the two "real" lists. As this can't be the only one, you'll have to create a third one holding the public key for this.

You can actually achieve this using rather complex split-and-join operations, similarly as described in [*"Migrating GPG master keys as subkeys to new master key"*](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/62480/19837). This will require deep knowledge of [RFC 4880 (OpenPGP)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880).

In the end, you should have a structure similar to:

- Primary key 1

  - UID list1@foo.bar
  - shared subkey
  - subkey 1
- Primary key 2

  - UID list2@foo.bar
  - shared subkey
  - subkey 2
- Primary key both

  - UID both@foo.bar
  - shared subkey

### Solution 2: reencrypting

In my opinion, implementing an MTA that performs reencryption for the individual recipients would be a better option. And not only reencrypting for both lists, but each recipient individually.

Consider what happens if somebody leaves one of the mailing lists. You're not able to revoke his access without sharing new (sub)keys to all of the members!

There seems to exist an inactive modification for mailman for this purpose, or you loop the list through an encrypting MTA like [geam](http://www.g10code.com/p-geam.html).

Comment: Hi Jens. Thanks for your 2 suggestions. I had in mind doing something like you say in solution 1, but didn't know how to achieve it, so I failed when exporting the subkey, because it was bound to the ID. That link you say looks helpful. I will try and later report. Thank you!